# Static IP in a VirtualBox VM that's "mobile"

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, dhcp

I've seen the great answers on configuring a static IP in Ubuntu.  My challenge is that I've got a VM running on my laptop for use in doing demos where the router and gateway addresses change significantly.  So, this morning I was on a 10.x network and now I'm on a 192. network.

Is there a technique to create a static that will work regardless of where I am?  Or is this more of a "edit your host machine's hosts file when you arrive" and leave the VM on DHCP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a script to determine what network it is on and set the IP accordingly.  e.g., if I'm on a 10.x network, get 10.1.2.3, and if I'm on a 192.x network, get 192.168.1.52.  I can help you write this if you give me a list of preferences you want.  Here's what I need:

1. What networks you expect to be on (10.2.3.x, 192.168.1.x, 169.254.x.x, 192.168.199.x, 10.54.43.x, etc)
2. What IP you want to get on those networks